# Caliburn micro, access conductor page from view model

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

Im building Windows Phone 8 app which has pivot control (conductor page) with few pivot items (user controls).

In my main pivot/conductor page I have defined ProgressIndicator like this:

```
<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsVisible="{Binding Loading}"
                             IsIndeterminate="{Binding Loading}"
                             Text="Loading..." />
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

How should I access the ProgressIndicator IsVisible binding from pivot items view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to use messaging.

Create say ProgressInidcatorChangeMessage with and Active bool property, subrscribe your Pivot page to handle the message (IHandle) and then send the message from your "pivot" ViewModels.